# Given the average of 15 students, and the average of 10 of them, what's the average of the other 5?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

The average value of a diagnostic test from $10$ students is $55$. If we add $5$ more student so the total number of students is $15$, the average value changes to $53$.

How much is the average value from the last $5$ students?

Comment: Why the upvotes?

Comment: Question closed dude.

Comment: Not my concern, "dude". That you start using the site properly, on the other hand, would be good news. At the moment you are squarely misusing it...

Comment: Sorry for bad english

Comment: Not a language problem. (But this diversion was a nice try, I guess.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the average of the the first $10$ students is $55$, then the sum of their total scores is $55 \cdot 10 = 550$. If you add $5$ more students and the average is $53$, then the total would be $$15 \cdot 53=795$$ Subtract $550$ from that to get the total for the $5$ new students, which is $245$. Then, simply divide that by $5$ to get the average, which is $$\dfrac {245}5=49$$

Comment: Question Closed :)

Answer (score 3):

SuomynonA already gave the solution, but I advise to write your problem in equation form to solve it. This is a better and more general way to solve these kind of issues.

The equation for this problem is:

$$10 \times 55 + 5x=15 \times 53$$

Please don't just solve the equation, but have a look why it's build up like this.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate The simply total value of 10 students

$$10×55=550$$

Now, calculate the total value of 15 students,

$$15×53=795$$
Calculate the total value of 5 students,
$$795-550=245$$
Calculate the average of 5 students,
$$\dfrac{245}{5}=49$$